# rails 3 load different partials in mailer action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

So I have one layout for 2 mail actions: `signup_email` and `change_password`

```
  def signup_email(user, url)
    @user = user
    @url  = url
    mail(to:user.username, subject:"Welcome to Clubicity!", template_path: "mail_templates", template_name: "system")
  end

  def change_password(username,url)
    @url = url
    mail(to:username,subject:"Clubicity - password recovery", template_path: "mail_templates", template_name: "system")
  end
```

I managed to get the one layout for this 2 actions, but now in this layout I need to render 2 different partials depending on what action is called, signup or change_pwd..

I've looked in RailsGuides and api.rubyonrails.org and they say only about templates.

Please, need help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it using mail layouts like this

```
  def change_password(username,url)
    @url = url
    mail(to:username,subject:"Clubicity - password recovery") do |format|
      format.html { render :layout => 'mail_templates/system'}
    end
  end

  def signup_email(user, url)
    @user = user
    @url  = url
    mail(to:user.username, subject:"Welcome to Clubicity!") do |format|
      format.html { render :layout => 'mail_templates/system'}
    end
  end
```

and in the layout just put **<%= yield %>**

and rock'n'roll!

Comment: So, for first action your mail layout is app/views/layouts/mail_templates/system.html.erb,
your mail view is app/views/user_mailer/change_password.html.erb ?

Comment: exactly.. so I have one full template and mailer views loading into this layout.. except the path for the change_password is not  views/user_mailer/ but views/mailer/change_password.html.erb

Comment: Thank you, will use your method:)
Just correct pls  <% yield %> to  <%= yield %>.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to use one file for different actions. Of course you have to define actions in templates.

I propose to make one view file for each action.

For using one layout just add `<%= render 'email_header' %>` to the top and `<%= render 'email_footer' %>` to the bottom of each view. Also make `_email_header.html.erb` and `_email_footer.html.erb` with appropriate markup.

Comment: doesn't look quite right to me this way... I'll wait for another answer, if there will be no other solutions I'll have to do it your way. Thanks any way for youtime.